# How we find total sizes or total counts of the table using selenium. I need total count

Tags: selenium

```
 **Source Code**:

    <tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="alpha">
    <tr class="beta">
    <tr class="alpha">
    <tr class="beta">


**My code** :

CourseTable = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tbody[aria-live=\"polite\"]"));
CoursesList= CourseTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
OldCoousesize=CoursesList.size();
System.out.println(OldCoousesize);
```

It will return size or count of the current page .But i need total count of the records from all pages.Is there any way to get total count.

Comment: Create a variable, iterate with loop through all pages and add count to variable on each page. You cannot handle all pages at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can interact only with the elements currently in the DOM. You need to go through all the pages and get the count from each one separately.